# C++ How do I compare a 'int' or 'double' to a char using ASCII code? Is it possible?

Tags: c++, char, integer, compare, ascii

I am writing a simple math calculator that takes two inputs (one for number and one for the operation, like +, -, *, /) with an 'Undo' function.

I initialized the following:

// 'value' is the final result and 'user' is the user's input

```
double value = 0
double user 
char operation

// History of previous values
list<double> history;
```

The main code looks like this:

```
// Display the initial value (0)
cout << "=>" << value << endl;
    
    while(true)
    {
        cin >> user;
        cin >> operation;
        
        // Addition
        if(operation == '+')
        {
            history.push_front(value);
            value += user;
            cout << "=>" << value << endl;
        }
        
        // Subtraction
        if(operation == '-') 
        { 
            history.push_front(value);
            value -= user;
            cout << "=>" << value << endl;      
        }
        
        // Multiplication
        if(operation == '*') 
        { 
            history.push_front(value);
            value *= user;
            cout << "=>" << value << endl;   
        }
        
        // Division
        if(operation == '/') 
        { 
            history.push_front(value);
            value /= user;
            cout << "=>" << value << endl;  
        }
        
        if(operation == 'u' || operation == 'U')
        {
            value = history.front();
            cout << "=>" << value << endl;
        }
```

The problem here is I am asking for two inputs and I am asking for the number first (which is of type double) rather than the operation (type char). So if user input 'u' for the first input it'd start freaking out.

Is there any way for me to compare `value` with a letter (in this case, u and U) using ascii codes? And how'd I do so if there is?

I tried declaring another `char undo = 'u'` then compare with `if(user == undo)` but it does not work.

Comment: Have you considered reading input into a `std::string` first, then inspecting what was read, and converting the string into a `double` value, if necessary, or otherwise handling the text string pretty much as the shown code does?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I didn't think about that, thank you.